# Is it possible to open my iOS app from instagram through a deeplink?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, deep-linking

I do have a professional Instagram account selling clothes, and I also have an iOS app for this.

My goal is to redirect the user from instagram to my iOS app via a deeplink, when the user presses a tagged item, or on the "go to shop" button.
Right now, it is redirecting to the instagram shop, but i would like to redirect it to my app.
Here is a screenshot to understand better :

[image]

Is it something technically possible ?
I do not find any concrete documentation on this topic.

Thank you !

Comment: Yess It is possible ... You need to deep dive into it.
You you are thinking to open your app on click of any url(link) Then you can... But if u wanna to have a customised button instagram and then open your app, then u need to talk with instagram help.

Comment: Look into Firebase Dynamic Links

Comment: thanks for the answers! I added more details, my goal is to open my app when I tap on a pin post for example, do you think it is also possible ? i did not see any brand doing that, so it might be an instagram limitation maybe ..

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It is possible!
There are a few ways to skin this cat :P But this [link](https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97) will do a good explanation of what you'd need to do. You're essentially just creating a hyperlink into your app :)

You can also check out Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content?preferredLanguage=occ)

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Do you think it would be possible to achieve this on tagged items in a post also ?

Comment: If you can put a link inside of that pin, it should theoretically still be possible @UgoMarinelli

Comment: Were you able to achieve it? I think instagram will only open their internal browser and won't redirect to a native app autimatically @UgoMarinelli